# JSON.net loop through facebook json array

Tags: json, vb.net, facebook, facebook-graph-api, json.net

Hey all I am trying to figure out how to loop through a JSON array that looks like this:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": "1zzz87_1020zzzzzzz9403", 
      "from": {
        "id": "10zzzzzz487", 
        "name": "Tom zzzzz"
      }, 
      "story": "Tom zzzz shared YouVersion's photo.", 
      "picture": "https://fbcdn-sphotos-a-a.akamaihd.net/zzzzz/4948_n.jpg?xxx_210ce5zzzza8b3e", 
      "link": "https://www.facebook.com/YouVersion/photos/zzzz/?type=1", 
      "name": "Mobile Uploads", 
      "caption": "1 John 4:4 NASB", 
      "properties": [
        {
          "name": "By", 
          "text": "YouVersion", 
          "href": "https://www.facebook.com/YouVersion?ref=stream"
        }
      ], 
      "icon": "https://fbstatic-a.akamaihd.net/zzzzz.gif", 
      "actions": [
        {
          "name": "Comment", 
          "link": "https://www.facebook.com/1020zzzzz48z/posts/102zzzzzz79zzz43"
        }, 
        {
          "name": "Like", 
          "link": "https://www.facebook.com/102zzz33zz/posts/102zzzzz40279zz3"
        }
      ], 
      "privacy": {
        "value": ""
      }, 
      "type": "photo", 
      "status_type": "shared_story", 
      "object_id": "101zzzzzz2", 
      "application": {
        "name": "Facebook for iPhone", 
        "namespace": "fbiphone", 
        "id": "6zzzzzz9"
      }, 
      "created_time": "2014-09-21T02:04:20+0000", 
      "updated_time": "2014-09-21T02:04:20+0000"
    }, 
    {
      "id": "1zzzzzzz487_102zzzzzz3zz82", 
      "from": {
        "id": "1020431zzzzzz", 
        "name": "Tom zzzzzz"
      }, 
      "story": "Tom zzzzz shared Brian zzzzzz's photo.", 
      etc etc.....
```

From the example above, only **"data":** shows up once so I can not use that as the means to loop to the next story. As you see the story starts at **"id":** and goes all the way to **"updated_time":**. Then the next story to follow that one starts at **"id":** and goes all the way to **"updated_time":** as well.

I am using this code below:

```
Dim strJson As String       = File.ReadAllText("D:\winData\My Documents\jsonTEST.json")
Dim json As JObject         = JObject.Parse(strJson)
Dim thePostID As String     = DirectCast(json("data")(0)("id").ToString(), String)
Dim thePostType As String   = DirectCast(json("data")(0)("type").ToString(), String)
Dim thePosterID As String   = DirectCast(json("data")(0)("from")("id").ToString(), String)
Dim thePosterName As String = DirectCast(json("data")(0)("from")("name").ToString(), String)
Dim thePostTitle As String  = DirectCast(json("data")(0)("story").ToString(), String)
```

I can get the values I am in need of just fine, but it doesn't loop to get all the other ones past retrieving the first one.

I tried code like this:

```
For Each Row In json("id")(0)("id")
   MsgBox("here")
Next Row
```

But that doesnt seem to do anything but error out at the **json("id")(0)("id")**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for:

```
For Each Row In json("data")
    Console.WriteLine(Row("id"))
    Console.WriteLine(Row("type"))
    ' etc...
Next
```

Basically, grab the array that the `data` property corresponds to in the JSON and iterate over its members.

Comment: You got it, Andrew. Thanks!