# Deserialize JSON Invalid JObject Values

Tags: json, .net, vb.net, json.net

I am using Newtonsoft.JSON to desearlize a JSON request obtained by a weather API. However, I get this error:

> System.ArgumentException: 'Accessed JObject values with invalid key value: 0. Object property name expected.

I am using a JObject to deserialize my JSON since there are no square brackets. My JSON looks like this:

```
{
  "lat": 41.111,
  "lon": -100.111,
  "timezone": "America/Chicago",
  "timezone_offset": 0,
  "public_statements": [
    {
      "weather": "Sunny through the evening",
      "temp": "High: 63 Degrees. Low: 40 Degrees",
      "description": "Sunny Today. A high of 63 Degrees and a Low of 40 Degrees.",
      "tags": [
        "wr_report"
      ]
    },
    {
      "weather": "Clear through the night.",
      "temp": "High: 50 Degrees. Low: 40 degrees.",
      "description": "Clear tonight with a High of 50 degrees and a low of 40 degrees.",
      "tags": []
    }
  ]
}
```

I am trying to make access the `weather`, `temp`, and `description` of each report when given a certain index. I would eventually want to use a `For` loop to import the `weather`, `temp` and etc. into a list.

My code looks like this:

```
Dim jResults As JObject = JObject.Parse(result) 'variable "result" contains the JSON.


Dim tempReport As New List(Of String)()

For Each reports As JObject In jResults(0)("public_statements")
    Dim temp As String = reports("temp")
    tempReport.Add(temp)
Next
```

This code is supposed to take all the temperatures listed in the JSON (such as "High: 63 Degrees. Low: 40 Degrees" and "High: 50 Degrees. Low: 40 degrees." and put them into a list. How can I fix this?

Comment: `jResults(0)("public_statements")` ... `public_statements` can't be `jResults(0)`

Comment: Your `jResults` is an object, not an array. `public_statements` is. You got it inverted: `For Each report As JObject In jResults("public_statements")  tempReport.Add(report("temp")) next` -- You could build a class model to deserialize your JSON.

Comment: Basically a duplicate of [JSON.net loop through facebook json array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26007071/3744182) then.